canonical way to set a reset line at startup in verilog
(Total noob at FPGA)
For real hardware not simulation. I want to assert a global reset / clear signal on the first n clock cycles (maybe just 1)

well fortunately somebody thought it was clear enough and provided the perfect answer

Most FPGA have a built-on Power on Reset(PoR). You can use a declaration initialization or initial block that sets PoR state of any register. Then you can describe a state machine to set any signal after some number of cycles.
reg [3:0] PoRcounter = 3;
wire signal;

always @(posedge clk) if (PoRcounter != 0)
  PoRcounter <= PoRcounter - 1;
assign signal = (PoRcounter !=0);


so the POR is what implements the 'reg x = constant' functionality?

I thought 'initial ' blocks were only for sim runs

Most FPGA synthesis tool support as an initial value. Declaration initialisation was a later addition to Verilog. 2001
